# POST XML request to 'REST' service url from iPhone

Tags: xcode4, http-post

I m pretty much new to objective-C and strucked at a point.I have to POST XML request to rest service url and get the response from it .I m using NSMutableRequest.But couldn't see any response.Couldn't understand where I m going wrong ...

Request XML is like this:

```
<GetUserRequest xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/DModel" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<ID>456789</ID>
<UserEmail>John@yahoo.com</UserEmail>
</GetUserRequest>

My url is like this : http://192.158.0.104:8732/IServices/GetXml
```

MY code goes like this :

```
NSString *urlString1=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://192.158.0.104:8732/IServices/GetXml"];
NSMutableURLRequest *request=[[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init]autorelease];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString1]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
NSString *contentType=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"application/xml"];
[request addValue:contentType  forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-type"];

NSMutableData *postBody=[NSMutableData data];
[postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<GetUserRequest xmlns=\"http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/DModel\" xmlns:i=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\">"]dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<ID>456789</ID>"]dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<UserEmail>John@yahoo.com</UserEmail>"]dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/GetUserRequest>"]dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[request setHTTPBody:postBody];
NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse=nil;
NSError *error=[[NSError alloc]init];
NSData *responseData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&urlResponse error:&error];
NSString *rss=[[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding ];
NSlog(@"Response Code:%d",[urlResponse statusCode]);
if([urlResponse statusCode ]>=200 && [urlResponse statusCode]<300)
{
    NSLog(@"Response:%@",rss);
}
```

But I couldnot see anything in active console...

Any help would be appreciated ...

Comment: Have you searched for an answer on stackoverflow?

Comment: Yes I did check it and implemented this code ...

Comment: just look my ans on this que:-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12583667/xml-parsing-error-while-using-wcf-framework-for-web-services/12584067#12584067

Answer (score 0):

That code looks poor to me and doesn't contain enough error checking (`[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest]` can return `nil` when an error occurs).  Modify the end to:

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request 
                                             returningResponse:&urlResponse 
                                                         error:&error];
if (responseData != nil)
{
    NSString *rss = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData 
                                          encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding ];
    NSlog(@"Response Code:%d",[urlResponse statusCode]);
    if([urlResponse statusCode ]>=200 && [urlResponse statusCode]<300)
    {
        NSLog(@"Response:%@",rss);
    } 
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"Failed to send request: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
}
```

Comment: I tried ur code.If I put a breakpoint and check after this line NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request 
                                             returningResponse:&urlResponse 
                                                         error:&error];breakpoint is not entering to the code after that and console area shows nothing..not even rss value (may it be null or some thing) How can I do it?

Comment: First of all breakpoint is not entering this line if (responseData != nil)  to check whether it is nill or contains some data.Y breakpoint is not stopped at that line ?

Comment: OK looks like `responseData == nil`.  Put the breakpoint on the `[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:...]` line and step through with `F6`.

Comment: If responseData==nil then it should either show me error.i tried to check it with F6 and stops at a line 0x003fc7e8  <+0000>  jmp    *0x52673c and it is not moving forward.. donno y and in console I can see Single stepping until exit from function dyld_stub_GSEventRun, 
which has no line number information.

Comment: OK, stop running it in the debugger and just run it without breakpoints and see what appears on the console.

Comment: my view is loading with this data in console GNU gdb 6.3.50-20050815 (Apple version gdb-1705) (Fri Jul  1 10:50:06 UTC 2011)
Copyright 2004 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
GDB is free software, covered by the GNU General Public License, and you are
welcome to change it and/or distribute copies of it under certain conditions.
Type "show copying" to see the conditions.
There is absolutely no warranty for GDB.  Type "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-apple-darwin".sharedlibrary apply-load-rules all
Attaching to process 1135.